# Getting System.InvalidCastException error

Tags: c#

I want to save data from dataGridView to excel. I try it in two different computers. The difference between two comnputers is that one of them has Microsoft Office 2013(x64) and the other one has Microsoft Office 2019(x64). Microsoft Office 2019 is crack. Microsoft Office 2013 is original. My program works on Microsoft Office 2019 which is crack. However, it does not work on Microsoft Office 2013. It gives me an error. Also I use Visual Studio 2019.

**Error:**

```
System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast COM object of type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{000208D5-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' failed due to the following error: Kitaplık kaydedilmemiş. (0x8002801D (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED)).'
```

**Code:**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Excel.Application excel = new Excel.Application();
    excel.Visible = true;
    object Missing = Type.Missing;
    Workbook workbook = excel.Workbooks.Add(Missing);
    Worksheet sheet1 = (Worksheet)workbook.Sheets[1];
    int StartCol = 1;
    int StartRow = 1;
    for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        Range myRange = (Range)sheet1.Cells[StartRow, StartCol + j];
        myRange.Value2 = dataGridView1.Columns[j].HeaderText;
    }
    StartRow++;
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
        {

            Range myRange = (Range)sheet1.Cells[StartRow + i, StartCol + j];
            myRange.Value2 = dataGridView1[j, i].Value == null ? "" : dataGridView1[j, i].Value;
            myRange.Select();
        }
    }
}
```

What seems to be a problem here?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/258475/unable-to-cast-com-object-of-type-39microsoftoffic.html
Hope this helps

Comment: @HardipsinhJadeja Thanks. DanielZhang-MSFT's answer helped me to solve my problem.